# adb run-as copy file

Tags: android, adb, cp

I have debbugable app, and I need to copy file to phone, and back after. I use this command and receive error.

```
adb shell run-as app cp /data/data/app/shared_prefs/app_preferences.xml /storage/emulated/0
cp: /storage/emulated/0/app_preferences.xml: Operation not permitted
```

I tryied to edit file

```
adb shell run-as app "echo test > /data/user/0/app/shared_prefs/app_preferences.xml"
/system/bin/sh: can't create /data/data/app/shared_prefs/app_preferences.xml: Permission denied
```

But if I try

```
adb shell
run-as app
echo test > /data/user/0/app/shared_prefs/app_preferences.xml
```

This way I able to edit file, but cp not. Also via Android Studio I can save and upload file.

In total, how to edit in one command or copy file?

Comment: Most likely the app you use as run-as target does not have the permission to write to `/storage/emulated/0` I would try to solve it this way `adb shell` and then `run-as app "cat /data/data/app/shared_prefs/app_preferences.xml" > /storage/emulated/0/com.jetscootert_preferences.xml` That way file writing should be done using adb shell permissions.

Comment: It is returns empty file. But source file isnt empty

Comment: You can try if you can see the file content at all: `run-as app cat /data/data/app/shared_prefs/app_preferences.xml`

Comment: Source file isnt empty